# What is the cause of failure in this example given in the Go Memory Model document?

Tags: concurrency, go

In the Go Memory Model document http://golang.org/ref/mem it gives the following example:

```
var a string
var done bool

func setup() {
    a = "hello, world"
    done = true
}

func main() {
    go setup()
    for !done {
    }
    print(a)
}
```

It then says the following of this example.

> "there is no guarantee that the write to done will ever be observed by main, since there are no synchronization events between the two threads. The loop in main is not guaranteed to finish."

So if the write to the **done** variable may not be observed by **main**, that would seem to suggest that the **setup()** function never runs. Is that correct? If so, would it be because the program was reordered to move the **go setup()** after the **for !done {}** loop? Or would there be some other reason?

I assume that if the **go setup()** statement is actually able to be executed, then the **setup()** function would be guaranteed to be called and **done** would be set. Is that right?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many things that can go wrong. It could:

1. schedule the setup goroutine for after the first goroutine completes.
2. make the change to a local register instead of the global. (incrementing integers would be much faster)
3. partially update (unlikely with a bool, but a string could be problematic)
4. drop the change entirely

In the current implementation, something very close to problem 1 occurs. Assuming GOMAXPROCS=1, `for !done { }` will never yield to the scheduler. This means setup would never run.

A goroutine yields on memory allocation, channel communication, syscalls, and randomly on function calls. That is a non-exhaustive list. But it will not yield on a for loop that does nothing. You need some form of synchronization to ensure the goroutine eventually yields.

---

I would like to point out that it doesn't matter whether there is a problem or not in the current implementation. The point is they have declared it is not guaranteed and when they implement optimizations, they will assume code where done is observed by main and code where it is not observed as the same.

Comment: I think I see what you're saying, but could you please clarify what "for after the first runs" means? I'm not completely understanding what you're saying there.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. That makes more sense. And yes, I understand that the point is to not write code like the given examples. I just want to make sure I understand the issues so I'm sure to spot the same thing in a different form. :-)

Answer (score 1):

> [The Go Programming Language Specification](http://golang.org/ref/spec)
>
> [Go statements](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Go_statements)
>
> A "go" statement starts the execution of a function call as an
>   independent concurrent thread of control, or goroutine, within the
>   same address space.
>
> The function value and parameters are evaluated
>   as usual in the calling goroutine, but unlike with a regular call,
>   program execution does not wait for the invoked function to complete.
>   Instead, the function begins executing independently in a new
>   goroutine. When the function terminates, its goroutine also
>   terminates. If the function has any return values, they are discarded
>   when the function completes.

The `setup()` goroutine may not run: "unlike with a regular call, program execution does not wait for the invoked function to complete."

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm not understanding which part of that paragraph implies that setup() may not run. The only way I could see that happening would be with code reordering of the "go setup()" statement and the "for !done {}" statement. Is that the case? If not, it would seem that the loop would block execution until the "done" is set.

Comment: @sixfingeredman: No code reordering, just concurrency: "A 'go' statement starts the execution of a function call as an
independent concurrent thread of control, or goroutine, within the
same address space."

Comment: But if there's no code reordering, then the goroutine would start up and would execute the "setup()" function, and the main thread would continue, and run into the "for !done {}" loop, wouldn't it?

Comment: @sixfingeredman: One processor and `main` never relinquishes control or `GOMAXPROCS=1`.

Comment: Ah, so the issue would be specific to a single OS thread situation, so that the "for" loop would actually block the "setup()" function even though it's a separate goroutine. Is that right?

Comment: @sixfingeredman: That or perhaps `setup` waiting for I/O, system call, channel, or scheduler or perhaps `setup` takes along time.